# What factors make a wizard better at verbal spells?

Tags: harry-potter

It would be silly to believe that people can become greater wizards just by learning more and more spells (and the right pronunciations..): what could some of the other factors be that really enhance the ability of a wizard in terms of his magic: Wand usage? Concentration?

Comment: Memory training? You can learn a spell every day, but if you don't remember them they're not really useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Magical power**.

  - Barty Crouch "Fake Moody" indicates that 4th-years can't cause more than a nosebleed on him if they cast *Avada Kedavra* because it requires power
  - Neville is particularly non-powerful at spells (even his crowning achievement in the entire fight is basically going all Conan-the-Destroyer style swordplay, followed by his organizational skills, his horticulture skills, and "getting" how RoR works).
- Some spells require specific **emotional tone and strength of emotions**

  - *Expecto Patronum* - you need happy emotions (and something else intangible, as very few people - even adults - can produce corporeal Patronus)
  - Bellatrix tells Harry you have to really want to hurt someone to cast *Crucio*
- **Fine motor control for wand movement**.

  - Flick and swish for *Wingardium levi**o**sa* is a very precise movement and can cause an explosion if done wrong (see Seamus).

---

However, it appears that rote learning may be enough for a **vast majority of spellcasting:**

- Harry taught pretty advanced defensive spells to 5th years in DA. Including to aforementioned Neville, once he got over his mental blocks.
- Crabbe wasn't exactly mental giant or super powerful mage, but masterered Fienfyre in 7th year.

Answer (score 4):

The effects of a spell depends on different factors, amongst which

- the inner power of the wizard or witch,
- the wand, and their connection,
- the realisation of the spell (see below), and
- the particular circumstances.

To be able to cast a spell, a wizard or a witch needs

- magical ability (squibs, muggles, etc. can't),
- a wand or some channeling method (note that some powerful wizards may, for some spell, cast it without it),
- the right gesture,
- the right incantation (including pronunciation),
- the right concentration/state of mind/imagination/...

For example, many in the wizarding community have troubles with the Patronus Charm, because of its required mental focus.

I am not aware of any specifics on whether or not it is possible to train the inner ability of the wizards. But the right training, and the right mind certainly help a wizard to be more powerful. And learning more spells make you more versatile. Not necessarily more powerful.

I hope this answers your question..?

Comment: There are no magical squids? :-p

Comment: that'd be scary if they did :-D

Comment: Just think how many wands a magical squid could wield!